# Replace text to translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I opened a webstore with volusion.  At the checkout page, there is wording: 'Your Cart' that I need to replace, because I'll have different translations.  I can't find any code that changes that.

This is what I see with Firebug:

```
<table id="v65-cart-moreItems" border="0" align="center" width="96%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
<h2 class="v65-your-cart-title">Your Cart</h2>
```

and with Firebug, I could check the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatCart() {
        jQuery(function () {
            var path = '/a/c/shoppingcart.css';
            if (document.createStyleSheet) {
                document.createStyleSheet(path);
            } else {
                cssTag = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + path + '"  />';
                jQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).append(cssTag);
            }
            VJS.v65Cart.Layout.moveRemoveButtons().moveArticleText().dividerAfterItems().swapCheckoutPaths().swapQTYandPrice().moveCouponForm().moveRecalcTotal().addHeader('Your Cart').formatCellSpacing(2).zebraStripes().init();
            if (jQuery('#v65-cart-shipping-details-wrapper').length > 0) {
                VJS.v65Cart.Layout.formatShipping();
            }
        });
    }
    if (typeof jQuery == 'function') {
        if (VJS.v65Toolkit.checkPage('shoppingcart.asp')) {
            var $layoutSettings = jQuery('#v65-layout-mode');
            if ($layoutSettings.length > 0) {
                if ($layoutSettings.attr('data-cart') == 'storedot') {
                    VJS.v65Toolkit.injectTag({
                        'type': 'script',
                        'url': 'a/j/vjs-shoppingcart.js',
                        'callback': formatCart,
                        'cache': false,
                        'node': 'script'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with volusion, but it looks like you can target the title using jquery like so:

```
$('.v65-your-cart-title')
```

and just change it with .html('Your new title')

so it becoms

```
$('.v65-your-cart-title').html('Your new title')
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line of code

```
VJS.v65Cart.Layout.moveRemoveButtons().moveArticleText().dividerAfterItems().swapCheckoutPaths().swapQTYandPrice().moveCouponForm().moveRecalcTotal().addHeader('Your Cart').formatCellSpacing(2).zebraStripes().init();
```

Methods are chained from one to the other. This means, each method continues to effect the same object, as each one returns a reference to that object.

These are all modifying `layout`, so that seems promising. In addition, towards the end, you see

```
.addHeader('Your Cart')
```

I would suggest updating the text there for your translation.

Edit: If you have trouble finding the line of code, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  and search for  "*addHeader*"

Comment: the thing is i do not have access to this script.. so i cannot change the text.. they told me i need a custom script to change it..

Comment: Then @idor_brad 's solution looks to be a fine one.

Answer (score 0):

Edited. This should do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.v65-your-cart-title').text('new text here');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the thing is i do not have access to this script.. so i cannot change the text.. they told me i need a custom script to change it..

Comment: This is what you would put in the custom script.

Comment: Just put this in a `$(document).ready` and it should work fine

Comment: @ngmiceli can you put the whole custom script ready.. sorry guys, im not that familiar with it.. thank you!